# Make an Excel PivotTable column span several spreadsheet columns

Tags: excel

I am trying to create an invoice template using a PivotTable.

Because of the way the content around the PivotTable is designed, I need one of the columns of the PivotTable to span several spreadsheet columns as if I had used the "Merge Cells" feature to make the column (and thus the entire PivotTable) wider.

Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You could however consider using spill functions such as FILTER, UNIQUE combined with SUMIFS, preferably inside a LET-function, to achieve the same result as a PivotTable, but with better design flexibility. Add some illustrations/examples of what you are trying to build, and I might give you some ideas.

Comment: With all the information that you've just given me I can take it from here. Thank you for your answer Thomas.